# How to return the render_template and response together in a page in flask python

Tags: python, flask, lstm, web-deployment, forecasting

I m currently deploying my LSTM model using flask python, The question is how do I return the `render_template` and `response` together in a page, and also How do I pass my `transform` value to as Y-axis data and `curr_date` to as X-axis data in the graph, please share me some tips, Thanks in advance!

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, make_response, request, render_template, session
from pandas import DataFrame
import io
from datetime import datetime
from io import StringIO
import csv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pickle
import os
from keras.models import load_model
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
import datetime
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

 


app = Flask(__name__)



@app.route('/')
def form():
    return render_template('index.html')



def create_dataset(dataset, look_back=1):
            data = []
            for i in range(len(dataset)-look_back-1):
                    a = dataset[i:(i+look_back), 0]
                    data.append(a)
            return np.array(data)
    



@app.route('/transform', methods=["POST"])
def transform_view():
 if request.method == 'POST':
    f = request.files['data_file']
    if not f:
        return "No file"

    
    stream = io.StringIO(f.stream.read().decode("UTF8"), newline=None)
    csv_input = csv.reader(stream)
    stream.seek(0)
    result = stream.read()
    df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(result), usecols=[1])
    
    #extract month value
    df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(result))
    matrix2 = df2[df2.columns[0]].to_numpy()
    list1 = matrix2.tolist()
     
    # load the model from disk
    model = load_model('model.h5')
    dataset = df.values
    dataset = dataset.astype('float32')
    scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
    dataset = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)
    look_back = 1
    dataset_look = create_dataset(dataset, look_back)
    dataset_look = np.reshape(dataset_look, (dataset_look.shape[0], 1, dataset_look.shape[1]))
    predict = model.predict(dataset_look)
    transform = scaler.inverse_transform(predict)

    X_FUTURE = 12
    transform = np.array([])
    last = dataset[-1]
    for i in range(X_FUTURE):
        curr_prediction = model.predict(np.array([last]).reshape(1, look_back, 1))
        last = np.concatenate([last[1:], curr_prediction.reshape(-1)])
        transform = np.concatenate([transform, curr_prediction[0]])
  
    transform = scaler.inverse_transform([transform])[0]

    dicts = []
    curr_date = pd.to_datetime(list1[-1])
    for i in range(X_FUTURE):
        curr_date = curr_date +  relativedelta(months=+1)
        dicts.append({'Predictions': transform[i], "Month": curr_date})


    new_data = pd.DataFrame(dicts).set_index("Month")
    ##df_predict = pd.DataFrame(transform, columns=["predicted value"])

def index(chartID = 'chart_ID', chart_type = 'line', chart_height = 550):
    chart = {"renderTo": chartID, "type": chart_type, "height": chart_height}
    series = [{"name": 'Month', "data": [1,2,3]}]
    title = {"text": 'Time Series Sales Predicting'}
    xAxis = {"categories": ['xAxis Data1', 'xAxis Data2', 'xAxis Data3']}
    yAxis = {"title": {"text": 'Sales'}}
          

    response = make_response(new_data.to_csv(index = True, encoding='utf8'))
    response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=result.csv"
    return render_template('index.html', response, chartID=chartID, chart=chart, series=series, title=title, xAxis=xAxis, yAxis=yAxis)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port = 9000, host = "localhost", passthrough_errors=True)
```

Comment: `make_response` can't be used with `render_template` since it already returns a response to the browser. What you could do maybe is to to serve a regular webpage using `render_template` and add a download link/button in your Jinja template, so the user can download the CSV file on demand. Although it is possible to trigger the download link automatically, for example using Javascript.

Comment: @Anonymous oh Its mean I have to store the new CSV file to the database and then the user only can download from the download button or link?

Comment: @Anonymous when save the data to new CSV file, the return function is either return `response` or none, so the its should be return response, In this case, what should I do for next ?

Comment: @Anonymous Please Help